# Angular nan value change

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

How can I change a Nan value in some columns of a table?

I have a table and in each cell at the end of each column, it gives the sum of the values of that corresponding column. But some of the values need not be added. So how it results in a nan value.

So can I change it using ngif anf isnan?

Comment: It's better to give your code, so that we can find the problem.
so how u calculate the sum ? if u had initialized by 0, there won't be nan

Comment: Please add code in your post so we can understand better

Comment: You could use a pipe to transform the value if the value is NaN